# Parallelize R code using snowfall package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snowfall

I am trying to run my R code in parallel. Following is the toy example in which myfunc function returns a number.

```
library(snowfall); 
sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=5)
a <- 1 : 10000
sfExport("a")
parwrapper <- function(i){
        mysimulation <- myfunc(b=30,c=a[i])
        return(mysimulation)}
sfapply(1:10000,parwrapper)
```

This is the error that I get.
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  5 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "myfunc"

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

The error clearly states the problem. `parwrapper` calls a function `myfunc`. This function is not defined. In addition you might have to export the object `sfExport('myfunc', 'parwrapper')`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, myfunc is a function from one of the R packages.

Comment: Fair enough. It is not a part of the `snowfall` library, so it was not clear from the example. In this case you'd have to use `sfLibrary([package name])` in order to export the library with the package contained. Alternatively the `foreach` package, `future` package and `parallel` package might be better at picking up dependencies automatically.

Comment: Following is the error:sfLibrary("rpact")
Error in sfLibrary("rpact") : 
  Stop: error loading library on slave(s): "rpact"

Comment: Now this is where i will fall short. From the error it sounds like `rpact` is not installed. You could check whether each slave-node has it installed using `sfClusterEval("rpact" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))` which should return `TRUE` for each node if the package is installed.

Comment: Yes it returns TRUE for each node. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I am sorry to say i am short for an answer here. I'd try another parallel package. The foreach package would be something like:`library(foreach);library(doParallel)registerDoParallel(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(5));foreach(x = 1:10000, .combine = c, .multicombine = TRUE, .packages = 'rpact')%dopar% { list(parwrapper(x)) `. The parallel package would look similar to snowfall: `library(parallel); nc <- 5; cl <- makeCluster(nc); clusterEvalQ(cl, library(rpact)); clusterSapply(cl, 1:10000, parwrapper)`.

Comment: Great. I will go with foreach package. How many nodes do you recommend? In the above example i used 5. If i use 10 then does it make significant difference?

Comment: that depends on the task, computer and system your on. In general it comes with experience, but never more than  `parallel::detectCores() - 1` (mostly my default). There's a lot to parallel computing, and if your tasks are possible to [vectorize](https://win-vector.com/2019/01/03/what-does-it-mean-to-write-vectorized-code-in-r/) this is often simpler and faster than what one was doing while performing parallel computing. This comes with trial-and-error, and stackoverflow has many well written answers to parallel computing questions. Especially on the `parallel` and `foreach` package.